# Displaying strings based upon certain alphabet letters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why my code isn't working. I'm creating a function that takes in a letter of the alphabet. If the letter is a, e, i, o or u then my program should display a message indicating that the entered letter is a vowel. If the letter is y then my function should display a message indicating that sometimes y is a vowel, and sometimes y is a consonant. Otherwise my function should display a message indicating that the letter is a consonant.

Here's my code

```
function vowelOrCons(letter) {
  if((letter) === 'a'; 'e'; 'i'; 'o'; 'u') {
    return 'vowel';
  } else if {
   ((letter) === 'y') {
     return 'vowel or consonant';
  } else if {
   ((letter) === "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", 
    "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "z")
     return 'consonant';
    }
    else
    {
     return 'Your entry is invalid';
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to learn Javascript better so I appreciate any help, resources, and/or explanations regarding my work, thanks!

Comment: it looks like a new language ...

Comment: @NinaScholz Died.. :)

Comment: @codeintech3 did any of these answers help you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes all answers and explanations were very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You problem is syntax.

```
if ((condition || another-condition) && condition) {
}
else if (some-other-condition) {
}
else {
}
```

Now concerning the checking, it can be shorten by using `includes` string method.

```
const firstLetter = letter.charAt(0);
if ("aeiou".includes(firstLetter)) { .. }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and return if `true` with the message.

This code features the early exit approach by taking an `if` clause and return. The advantage is to omit else parts because the return exits the function.

```js
function vowelOrCons(letter) {
    letter = letter.toLowerCase();
    if ('aeiou'.includes(letter)) {
        return 'vowel';
    }
    if (letter === 'y') {
        return 'vowel or consonant';
    }
    if ('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'.includes(letter)) {
        return 'consonant';
    }
    return 'Your entry is invalid';
}

console.log(vowelOrCons('a'));
console.log(vowelOrCons('b'));
console.log(vowelOrCons('1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok this need a bit of work. 
Take a look at the fixed code below. 
First off we move the test letters to arrays and used index of.
Then we fixed syntax issues and added test log at end.

```
  function vowelOrCons(letter) {
     let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
     let consonants = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", 
          "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "z"];
     if(vowels.indexOf(letter) > -1 ) {
       return 'vowel';
     } else if(letter === 'y') {
          return 'vowel or consonant';
    } else if(consonants.indexOf(letter) > -1 ){
           return 'consonant';
      } else {
         return 'Your entry is invalid';
      }

   }

console.log(vowelOrCons('a'));
console.log(vowelOrCons(''));
console.log(vowelOrCons('1'));
console.log(vowelOrCons('y'));
console.log(vowelOrCons('w'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you declare an array for vowels, one for consonants and then check if the letter intered is in the array but first check if it is a 'y' as shown below;

```
var vowels  = ['a', 'e', 'i',....]];
var consonants  = ['b', 'c', 'd', ....]];

if ('y' == letter) {
    // print your sentence
}
else if (/* letter is in the vowels array */) {
    // print your sentence
}
else if (/* letter is in the consonants array */) {
    // print your sentence
}
```

Good luck